# subversioning issues in NebBeans 6.9

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I am using `NetBeans IDE 6.9`. I am getting problems with my Netbeans SVN plugin.
I am getting this error when trying to update or show changes.

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
OPTIONS of '': SSL negotiation failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856
```

Comment: If you use other SVN client like "Tortoise" are you getting the same error? Also, is the URL where your SVN repo is pointing to working? Try opening it in a browser.

Comment: 1) Get yourself 7.0, 7.0.1 or 7.1 version 2) Are you using bundled subversion client or external?